# How will macOS behave when creating folders in /private/var/folders to mount a NFS share with?

Tags: macos, mount, nfs

I'm writing some software that can ideally mount and unmount multiple Network File System (NFS) locations dynamically.

To avoid clashing with local names I plan on generating a new temporary dir under `/private/var/folders` such as `/private/var/folders/6l/jbv4dn11301f7t2wm1r3mqlr0000gp/T/temp_mount.RXArBC` for each time I introduce a NFS share - in the hope that the OS can tidy up these folders on shutdown.

The worry I have is that for example, if I were to try to remove the folder before it was unmounted with something like `rm -r /private/var/folders/6l/jbv4dn11301f7t2wm1r3mqlr0000gp/T/temp_mount.RXArBC` - if the mount was not read-only, this would result in deleting the contents from the share (despite failing to delete the top-level folder as the mount service is presumably still holding a lock to it)!

I'm concerned the OS isn't expecting `/private/var/folders` to contain any mounts and thus pose a similar problem.

**Can someone confirm how it is the OS will behave in this scenario?** So far with my testing this hasn't happened, but I'm not sure this is indicative across the board for macOS users.

Another option I've considered is creating folders under somewhere like `~/Library/Application Support/MyAppDomain/MountDirs/` and performing tidy ups in my software as I go along, but I'm unsure how the OS will behave.

Answer (score 2):

No.

This is a system directory that contains things like logs, databases, your sleep image, etc.  It's not a directory that you should be mounting file shares to.  The purpose of the `/private` directory has already be discussed in the following posts:

- [What's the "Private" directory in OS X for?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/227846/119271)
- [Snow Leopard *private* folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/190446/119271)

Even the `automount` service doesn't mount shares to that directory, it's mounted in `/Volumes`.

Your best bet would be to either mount the share in a shared user space (i.e. `/Users/shared`) or within the users own home directory.

Comment: Isn't /Network the place to put nfs mounts? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Read it carefully.  *Networks: ...For example, if the user uses the Connect to Server command to mount a volume, paths begin with the /Volumes directory*